# MediaPicker Not Working with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I am new to xamarin.in  my project open gallery for select image for this i have used IMediaPicker interface.my code as below:

```
IMediaPicker mediaPicker;
ImageSource imageSource;
async void OnTapEntertainer(object sender, EventArgs args)
{          
   await TakePicture();
}

private async Task TakePicture()
{           
        mediaPicker = DependencyService.Get<IMediaPicker>();
        imageSource = null;
        var mediaFile = await mediaPicker.SelectPhotoAsync(new CameraMediaStorageOptions
        {
            DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Front,
            MaxPixelDimension = 400
        });
        imageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => mediaFile.Source);
        Imgmn.Source = imageSource;
}
```

I got **mediaPicker is null value** in this code.Please help me to solve this issue.
I have added capability  required for perform function.

Comment: Have you added Dependency Service class in .Droid library project to resolve IMediaPicker?

Comment: can you give me idea for add  dependency  on IOS and windows phone. i currently used Xlabs Dll for IMediaPicker interface.

Comment: can you give me idea for add  dependency on IOS and windows phone. i currently used Xlabs Dll for IMediaPicker interface.I have added Dll in All Platform but  not Work.

Comment: There only check the MediaPicket.cs in Droid project and add the file.

Comment: Can u give me guidance  for implement this..

Comment: You can see [example](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/28b6bf28b62ec183c422a6b6a02a5ee94a4dec9c/src/Platform/XLabs.Platform.Droid/Services/Media/MediaPicker.cs) and use `[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency (typeof (MediaPicker))]` [Reference](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/text-to-speech/#Android_Implementation)

Comment: i have done thanx vishnu...

Answer (score 1):

To use *MediaPicker* item from *XLabs* please double check you have comleted all the items below:

1. Add a reference to *XLabs.IoC* to all of your projects (PCL, Android, iOS, etc.)
2. Initialize *Resolver* using the following code snippet:

   ```
   var resolverContainer = new SimpleContainer();
   resolverContainer.Register<IMediaPicker, MediaPicker>()
   .Register<IDependencyContainer>(t => resolverContainer);
   Resolver.SetResolver(resolverContainer.GetResolver());
   ```

   Put this code before `Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init` method for each platform in your solution.
3. Use `var mediaPicker = Resolver.Resolve<IMediaPicker>();` to get the instance.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments following process resolves the issue:

Add Dependency Service class in .Droid library project to resolve IMediaPicker as given in [example](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/28b6bf28b62ec183c422a6b6a02a5ee94a4dec9c/src/Platform/XLabs.Platform.Droid/Services/Media/MediaPicker.cs) and use `[assembly:Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(MediaPicker))]` [Reference](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/text-to-speech/#Android_Implementation)